# Export powerbi embedded report to pdf. Does it need Azure AD?

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to export a power BI embedded report to pdf or pptx. using the API in C#.

I am following this link of the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to

It seems to fit what i need but there are some complications i don't understand.

It doesn't seems to address the complexity of creating the object Client:

```
// The 'Client' object is an instance of the Power BI .NET SDK
var export = await Client.Reports.ExportToFileInGroupAsync(groupId, reportId, exportRequest);
```

this appears to be an object of the class PowerBIClient, that to be instantiated needs a Uri and a TokenCredential.

For obtaining this token it seems that the only way is to have the report as an app on Azure AD.

Here my question: is this true? The only way to authenticate is to have an app on Azure AD, or i can export the report even without it?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the API in Azure follow similar authentication method . In case of Powerbi  you have two options.

- Application ID
- certtificate .
  Please read about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal)